# match two lists by common value (id)

Tags: python, list

I want create a new list such that the keys are used to match the roles.

For example two lists:

`[['9', u'bob'], ['18', u'alice']]`

`[['1', 'officer'], ['2', 'nurse'], ['9', 'teacher'],['18', 'unknown']]`

I'd like a new list that is:

`[['9', u'bob', 'teacher'], ['18', u'alice' 'unknown']]` or

`[[u'bob', 'teacher'], [u'alice' 'unknown']]`

Comment: lists dont have keys, but dictionary have

Comment: I understand that, but in this key my key for lists are the first index of each sublist.

Comment: `9` and `'9'` are different, how are you merging them ?

Comment: They are of the same type in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
names = [[9, u'bob'], [18, u'alice']]

roles = [[1, 'officer'], [2, 'nurse'], [9, 'teacher'],[18, 'unknown']]

mapper = dict(roles)
print([[x[0],x[1],mapper[x[0]]] for x in names])
```

assuming numbers in roles are of the same type i.e either integers or strings. In this case i have taken them as integers to match with names.

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = dict([[9, u'bob'], [18, u'alice']])

d2 = dict([[1, 'officer'], [2, 'nurse'], ['9', 'teacher'],['18', 'unknown']])

d = []
for k in d1:
    if str(k) in d2:
       d.append((k, d1[k], d2[str(k)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution -

```
  list_1 = [[9, u'bob'], [18, u'alice']]
  list_2 = [[1, 'officer'], [2, 'nurse'], [9, 'teacher'],[18, 'unknown']]
  new_list = []
  for i in list_1:
      for j in list_2:
          if i[0]==j[0]:
              new_list.append([i[1],j[1]])
```

Here's the one-liner for the same, but it puts elements in tuple -

```
  >> [(x[1], y[1]) for x in list_1 for y in list_2 if x[0] == y[0]]

  [('bob', 'teacher'), ('alice', 'unknown')]
```

To get a list of lists -

```
  >> [list(elem) for elem in [(x[1], y[1]) for x in list_1 for y in list_2 if x[0] == y[0]]]

  [['bob', 'teacher'], ['alice', 'unknown']]
```

Comment: This is what I want  but there has to be a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
L1 = [[9, u'bob'], [18, u'alice']]

L2 = [[1, 'officer'], [2, 'nurse'], ['9', 'teacher'],['18', 'unknown']]


final_List = []



for l1 in L1:    
    for l2 in L2:

        if str(l1[0]) == l2[0]:

            num_L = [l1[1],l2[1]]
            final_List.append(num_L)

print(final_List)

---------
Output:
---------
[['bob', 'teacher'], ['alice', 'unknown']]
```